# WPF RotateTransform behaviour is wierd

Tags: wpf, rotatetransform, transformgroup

I have a canvas which i want to rotate and translate. I am using RotateTransform and TranslateTransform combined in a TransformGroup.

I want to do the following steps with these transforms:

1. Rotate canvas with some angle.
2. Translate my canvas to some distance
3. Rotate canvas.

The center of rotation in step 1 and step 3 is same. But after performing step 2 i want to change center of rotation to a new position which should be in the center of the parent. But somehow this does not work.

```
Canvas myCanvas = null; //Canvas to rotate and move

RotateTransform RotTransform = new RotateTransform();
TranslateTransform trans = new TranslateTransform();
TransformGroup tgroup = new TransformGroup();

double RotationAngle = 0;
double speed = .50;

//This center point should remain same on the screen during all the transformations
Point Center = new Point(200, 200);

Initialize()
{
     tgroup.Children.Add(RotTransform);
     tgroup.Children.Add(trans);
}

    //This function moves the canvas in vertical direction by up or down arrow key
    public void MoveCanvas(Key key)
    {
        double speed = 0;
        if (key == Key.Up)
        {
            speed = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            speed = -1;
        }

        trans.Y += speed;
        myCanvas.RenderTransform = tgroup;
    }

    //This is the function to rotate the canvas
    public void RotateCanvas(Key key)
    {
        if (key == Key.Right)
        {
            RotationAngle += speed;
        }
        else if (key == Key.Left)
        {
            RotationAngle -= speed;
        }

        //Relocate the center point to the old center point i.e should be in the center of the container
        Point inv = tgroup.Inverse.Transform(Center);
        RotTransform.CenterX = inv.X;
        RotTransform.CenterY = inv.Y;

        RotTransform.Angle = RotationAngle;
        myCanvas.RenderTransform = tgroup;
    }
```

The problem is the center point, which i am resetting to the old point before every rotate. But after few moves and rotates this point goes somewhere outside the container or screen. Just want help to fix that one.

[image]

Where "C" the center of rotation for red rectangle, blue rectangle is the same red rectangle but translated. Now i need to rotate the blue rectangle but the center of rotation should be "C".

Comment: Do you want the second rotation to have the same origin as the first one or to always rotate around the middle of the canvas?

Comment: It should have the same origin. Right now if you dont change CenterX and CenterY of RotationTransform it always rotates on the middle of the canvas. For easy understanding if you make a mark on your screen in the center, the rotation should always be on that mark, even after the translation.

Comment: I have added an image for illustration of the problem.

Comment: If you need 2 rotations, can you add 2 `RotateTransform`s? `tgroup.Children.Add(RotTransform); tgroup.Children.Add(trans); tgroup.Children.Add(SecondRotTransform);`

Comment: Its not actually 2 rotations. You can think of canvas like a ground and the center is a ball which contentiously moving ahead in the ground it could be rotated hundreds of times. MoveCanvas method moves the ground in up direction and RotateCanvas rotate the ground right or left. So you may be moving forward(up) in the ground and you might be turning right or left in the ground so many times.